# Latest posts on all pages

Tags: posts

I would like to have the “latest” boxes on all my pages.
How can I fix that?

As it is now it works on the homepage, on the other only one box apperes and but the content is the same as the page it is in.

```
    <!--LATEST POSTS-->
<div class="center">
<?php if (is_page() ) { ?>
    <?php if(of_get_option('latstpst_checkbox') == "1"){ ?><?php get_template_part(''.$zn_lays = of_get_option('layout_images', 'layout1').''); ?><?php } else { ?><?php } ?>
<?php } else { ?>
    <?php get_template_part(''.$zn_lays = of_get_option('layout_images', 'layout1').''); ?>
<?php } ?>
<!--LATEST POSTS END-->
```

Comment: what does your code that actually queries for the latest posts look like?

Comment: to elaborate on @Milo's question: your posted code only calls a template - what is the code in the template which gets called by the code?

Answer (score 0):

Did see your code before, and my original solution would not have worked.  Do you have a link to the website this is on?

Maybe a long shot as not 100% sure what this is doing, have you tried changing the value == "1" to == "2" and see what happens?

Comment: I have tried changing 1-2 nothing happened.
I want all pages to get the same "latest posts" But every were but the home page the latest news box is posting the content from the page it is on. ransgaard.com

Comment: It was a longshot, I think your using this plugin or a theme with this in http://wptheming.com/options-framework-plugin/

Comment: I can see what you mean by looking at the website, I think there has to be a loop on your home page or a conditional statement like is_home that is making sure that more than one post is displayed.  I am not that experienced with PHP and trying to help out/participate in the forum a little more, but it might be a case of the blind leading the blind here!  Sorry.

Comment: It´s not just that it´s only one post displayed on the pages. The latest post on pages are just an excerpt from the page there on.

Comment: Yep I see that, I would consider heading over to the theme developers page and also asking the question there you have asked here.  I think and hopefully someone here can confirm "of_get_option" is not part of core Wordpress, but created by the theme/plugin, so the question is more specific and needs more information on what is happening with the theme/plugin.